# Shared EBS Volume in Launch Template for Autoscaling Group CDK

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cdk, autoscaling

I am trying to configure a shared EBS volume for an autoscaling group in AWS.

I cannot figure out how to get the external volume attached to instances using CDK constructs.

```js
    const sharedVolume = new ec2.Volume(this, 'shared-volume', {
      availabilityZone: 'us-east-1b',
      size: cdk.Size.gibibytes(100),
      volumeName: 'shared-host-volume',
      volumeType: EbsDeviceVolumeType.IO2,
      enableMultiAttach: true
    });
    const launchTemplate = new ec2.LaunchTemplate(this, 'web-launch-template', {
      associatePublicIpAddress: true,
      launchTemplateName: 'web-host-template',
      role: role,
      instanceType: ec2.InstanceType.of(ec2.InstanceClass.T3, InstanceSize.MEDIUM),
      machineImage: ec2.MachineImage.latestAmazonLinux2023(),
      userData: ec2.UserData.forLinux(),
      keyPair: keyPair,
      securityGroup: this.props.applicationSecurityGroup,
      blockDevices: [ ]
    });
    
    const scalingGroup = new asg.AutoScalingGroup(this, 'web-scaling-group', {
      autoScalingGroupName: 'web-scaling-group',
      vpc: props.vpc,
      vpcSubnets: {
        subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC
      },
      desiredCapacity: 1,
      maxCapacity: 2,
      minCapacity: 0,
      launchTemplate: launchTemplate,
    });
```

The blockDevices array on the LaunchTemplate expects a type of [BlockDeviceVolume](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ec2.BlockDeviceVolume.html).

What I need is an external [Volume](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ec2.Volume.html) with Multi-Attach enabled so I can allow at least 2 instances to attach to this device.